# How do I run SFML library on Mac using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, sfml

I installed SFML on my Mac using homebrew and I tried running a c++ file using SFML on visual studio code, but I end up with this error:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

The files are located in this directory /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1
I'm trying to implement this library without the use of other IDEs. I tried using CMake but it didn't make a difference.

I tried modifying includePath in the c_cpp_properties.json file but it still doesn't run.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/include/"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: You need to tell your compiler where to search for includes - it can't magically *guess* header file locations.

Comment: I didn't have a problem using cmake for this, so I'm wondering where you went off the rails in that effort. Can you also post your CMakeLists.txt in your question as well (separate code list apart from your actual code).